# Hololens2 Correct Usage of SpatialAnchors

Tags: hololens, openxr

I am trying to implement an Hololens 2 App using **SpatialAnchors** but it seems that I am not quite understanding the concept right. I am able to create, save and restore SpatialAnchors of the *Windows.Perception.Spatial namespace*, but whenever I restore them they are placed **relative to the start position of the headset**.

I use this snippet to **create an anchor**:

```
SpatialAnchor thisAnchor = SpatialAnchor.TryCreateRelativeTo(coord);
```

And this to get the **relative SpatialCoordinateSystem** (from this [post](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/discussions/10266:))

```
public static bool UseSGIPSceneCoordinateSystem(out SpatialCoordinateSystem sGIPSceneCoordinateSystem)
{
  // gain access to the scene object
  SceneObserverAccessStatus accessStatus = Task.Run(RequestAccess).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

  if (accessStatus == SceneObserverAccessStatus.Allowed)
  {  
    Scene scene = Task.Run(GetSceneAsync).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    sGIPSceneCoordinateSystem = SpatialGraphInteropPreview.CreateCoordinateSystemForNode(scene.OriginSpatialGraphNodeId);
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    sGIPSceneCoordinateSystem = null;
    return false;
  }
}
```

I use this method to **restore the SpatialAnchor** I need:

```
public bool GetAnchor(string id, out SpatialAnchor anchor)
{
 
    [...]
 
    _anchors = _anchorStore.GetAllSavedAnchors();
   
    foreach (var kvp in _anchors)
    {
        if(kvp.Key == id)
        {
            anchor = kvp.Value;
            return true;
        }
    }
 
    anchor = null;              
    return false;
}
```

And this to process the restored Anchor and get a **place in the scene** for it:

```
     public void SomeOtherMethod(SpatialAnchor anchor)
    {
        SpatialCoordinateSystem showcaseCoordinateSystem = anchor.CoordinateSystem;
     
        //get the reference SpatialCoordinateSystem
        if (!UseSGIPSceneCoordinateSystem(out SpatialCoordinateSystem referenceCoordinateSystem))
            return;
     
        _anchorMatrix = showcaseCoordinateSystem.TryGetTransformTo(referenceCoordinateSystem);
     
        System.Numerics.Matrix4x4 _notNullMatrix = _anchorMatrix.Value;
        Matrix4x4 unityAnchorMatrix = _notNullMatrix.ToUnity();
        anchorGameObject.transform.FromMatrix(unityAnchorMatrix);
    }
```

I think that I am using the **wrong SpatialCoordinateSystem** but can´t find information on how to get a SpatialCoordinateSystem which the HoloLens2 generates for the **physical spatial surrounding of the user** that is **persistent**.

I am using:
*Unity 2020.3.13f1
OpenXR Plugin 1.3.1
MRTK 2.7.3
MRTK-OpenXR 1.2.1
MRTK SceneUnderstanding 0.6.0*

I am also confused of the amount of different SpatialAnchor-Systems, reference coordinatesystems and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/spatial-anchors). Every post I find about SpatialAnchors seems to use a different approach. There seems to be SpatialAnchor-Systems for the Unity WLT, *UnityEngine.VR.WSA* with WorldManager, Azure Spatial Anchors,
*UnityEngine.XR.WindowsMR.WindowsMREnvironment*, etc.
And unless I havent overseen it, the microsoft documentation is not really clear about which one to use and how to use it right.

I would be really thankful if someone could bring some light into this issue.

I posted this question also on [forum.unity.com](https://forum.unity.com/threads/correct-usage-of-spatialanchors.1250971/)

Comment: For Unity 2019/2020 using OpenXR or the Windows XR Plugin, you need to use ARAnchorManager for all your hologram positioning needs. But in your code, the SpatialAnchor API you are using is legacy WinRT native APIs. For more information, please see: [World locking and spatial anchors in Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/spatial-anchors-in-unity?tabs=anchorstore)

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT Thank you! I was going to report back once I implemented it, but I haven't gotten around to it yet. One issue that has come up is that the namespace they use in the documentation _Microsoft.MixedReality.ARSubsystems.XRAnchorStore_ does not exist. I have installed MRTK OpenXR 1.2.1, MRTK 2.7.3 and the OpenXR Plug-In 1.3.1 and checked OpenXR in the XR Plug-In Management settings in unity, but there is no XR Anchoring. But _Microsoft.MixedReality.OpenXR_ & _UnityEngine.XR.WindowsMR_ seem to have anchoring functionality. Is the documentation wrong or have I missed something?

Comment: XRAnchorStore API is under the Microsoft.MixedReality.OpenXR namespace for now, please use this code to import this API:
`using Microsoft.MixedReality.OpenXR.ARSubsystems;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.OpenXR;`
 
Also, the ARAnchor scene demos the usage of ARFoundation to create free-world anchors, and the usage of the XRAnchorStore to persist these anchors between sessions: [AnchorsSample](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenXR-Unity-MixedReality-Samples/blob/main/BasicSample/Assets/ARAnchor/Scripts/AnchorsSample.cs)